# Protect Wordpress contacts form from spammers

Tags: wordpress, forms, contacts, spam

I have a project http://www.takoplius.lt. I am dealing with with a spam problem which comes through contact form. You can find this form in homepage right here (https://www.screencast.com/t/MvP7d7ZAiEe).

I tried to use Google recaptcha plugin, but it didn't help. In other words, when I put recaptcha shortcode in the form, recaptcha doesn't appear.

I tried akismet, but it didn't help as well.

Could you please help me to find the solution, which will protect my form from spam?

Comment: The solution is to find a working recaptcha plugin or implement it yourself.

Comment: All plugins work within pages, but in my case the form is not in the page. The form is written in seperate .php file.

Answer (score 0):

Hey add if possible use contact form 7 for formand add google recatcha on your form.

Also add below plugin to avoid spam mail.

```
URL - https://wordpress.org/plugins/stop-spammer-registrations-plugin/
```